# Separating DIVs in a responsive, percentage based layout

Tags: css

So far I have this **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/2zND2/7/)** - an arrangement of DIVs that using media queries changes as the width of the area reduces and maintains a layout that fits to 100% of the container width.

The problem I am having is trying to separate the `DIV` because the layout is percentage based.

My efforts to include a margin have so far failed to work in keeping everything perfectly formatted.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Here is the CSS...

```
#photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    #photos img {
    /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
    width: 20%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    #photos img {
    /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
    width: 25%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    #photos img {
    /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
    width: 50%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 300px) {
    #photos img {
    /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
    width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include a small, basic example of the code in your question? That way when you change/update your linked site this question could still be of use to future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you know how many images you want to see in a row you can use percentuage for margins as well.

For example. 5 images in a row:

```
img { width: 15% ; margin: 0 10% 10% 0;}

img:nth-child(5n+5) { margin: 0 0 10% 0; }
```

Comment: I am setting up the percentage width in CSS as a way of specifying how many images in each row so I will give this a try.

Comment: For every fifth child I used 5n, but that worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle margins with fullpage-width-based design by using 1-2% margins. For example,
if I have a row of 5 images, I have 18% width and 1% margin, so the horizontal width for one item (margin included) is 20%. Same for 23% + 1%(*2)  = 25%.

A 3-item row is more tricky. You can't perfectly size them, but you can try something like 32% + 0.5% margin. Luckily you don't want to have such row size!

For your responsive design, something like 18% + 1%, 21 + 2%, 42 + 4% and 88 + 6% would keep the margins somewhat in line.

Comment: Thanks and yes, I was avoiding odd value percentages for the reason you mentioned :)